# Number of edges and nodes in this control flow graph (CFG)?

Tags: software-design, flowchart, control-flow-graph

I'm having difficulty with nodes and arcs of a control flow graph (CFG).
Please, could someone help me by telling me how many edges and nodes are in this control flow graph (CFG) ?

[image]

Arcs and nodes control flow graph

Comment: There are 10 nodes and 12 edges between these nodes. What exactly is the problem in counting them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't do your work for you. But here are some hints that should help you:

- The nodes are numbered, so they should be easy to count. Just don't forget to add  `start` and `end`, which are also nodes.
- For the edges, it's more tricky, as **you might get confused by the graphical layout**. You need to count the edges from one node to another, without counting additional graphical elements that are there only for the nice layout. For example `7` goes to `end`, that's 1 edge even if there are two graphical arrows; or `1` goes to `end`, even if there are three different lines.

*Btw: control flow graphs are not UML. It's a family of models, which has flowcharts as specialization, and that has some  overlaps with UML activity diagrams.*

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. At this point I think that there are 10 nodes, is it true?
Please, could you explain the concept of edges? I don't undestand edge's concept and I think that if I understand this I will complete the exercice by myself

Comment: @kekokk the nodes are the boxes and the circles. The edges are a direct link between two nodes. Maybe this will help further: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I understand what is a node and now I am able to count the node but I still have trouble with the edges

Comment: Now that you inderstand what a node is, go on rach node and count the number of arrows that leave the node. Ignore all the other arrows.